# Download dependencies fails on Windows 2008 Server R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a C# application which I want to install on my Windows 2008 R2 server. The setup.exe needs to download certain dependencies from microsoft. During install I get the following error:

An error occurred downloading the following resource:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=249113

This happens although I have disabled IE ESC for the administrator account. (I am aware of the security related downsides of this).

Comment: if you manually install it, it work?

Comment: yes, if I install dependencies manually, the application works. The problem I want to solve is the automatic downloading of dependencies by the installer.

Comment: Its a homemade setup? as its in that code the problem imo